# How to write this complex MySQL query using three tables?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have below three table:

1. task Table -- task_id , activity_id(FOREIGN KEY),start_date,end_date
2. activity table -- activity_id , milestone_id(FOREIGN KEY), other_fields
3. Milestone table -- milestone_id , project_id, other_fields

Now I want result set like this

```
No_of_task(count) | no_activity | milestone_name
      5           :     2       :    ABC Milestone
```

I want to count end_dated task , count activity base on end_date task and milestone name.

For example, 1 milestone name Housing_Construction that has 5 activity and 20 different task ... some task end_dated so

5 task end of 3 activity of housing_construction like this.

**Task Table description**

```
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| activity_task_id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| milestone_activity_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| task                  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| description           | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| assign_to_employee_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| assign_date           | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| task_end_date         | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tasktime              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| status                | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| is_delete             | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| entry_employee_id     | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| edit_employee_id      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| createddatetime       | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| modifydatetime        | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nooftimesedit         | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| completion_date       | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**ActivityTable description**

```
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| milestone_activity_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| project_milestone_id  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| activityname          | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| activity_end_date     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| activity_description  | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| status                | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| is_delete             | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| entry_employee_id     | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| edit_employee_id      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| createddatetime       | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| modifydatetime        | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nooftimesedit         | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**milestone Table description**

```
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| project_milestone_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| project_id            | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| milestone             | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| milestone_description | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| milestone_end_date    | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| status                | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| is_delete             | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| entry_employee_id     | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| edit_employee_id      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| createddatetime       | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| modifydatetime        | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nooftimesedit         | smallint(6) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| noofdays              | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    count(distinct t.activity_task_id) No_of_task,
    count(distinct a.milestone_activity_id) no_activity,
    m.milestone_description milestone_name
from milestone m
inner join activity a
    on m.project_milestone_id = a.project_milestone_id
inner join task t
    on a.milestone_activity_id = t.milestone_activity_id
where t.status != 4
and t.task_end_date < curdate()
group by m.project_milestone_id,
    m.milestone_description;
```

Comment: Thanks For comment but where to put end date condition in this query ?

Comment: select t.count as No_of_task from 
(SELECT COUNT(activity_task_id) count from activity_task_details where status !=4 and task_end_date < curdate())

Comment: @hardikshah updated my answer. Please try and let me know

Comment: sorry i cant Up vote your answer they show me Error : reputation < 15

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JOIN` for this purpose, Use this following code,

```
SELECT COUNT(T.task_id) as no_of_task,
       COUNT(A.activity_id) as no_of_activity,
       MAX(M.milestone_name)  as milestone_name
FROM milestone M 
INNER JOIN activity A on M.milestone_id=A.milestone_id
INNER JOIN task T on T.activity_id =A.activity_id 
GROUP BY A.activity_id,T.task_id
HAVING T.end_date < curdate()
```

Comment: thanks for reply , i will try this, but where to put condition of outdated task ??  there are two fields in task start date , and end date, i need task count that has ended

Comment: after the `GROUP BY` you can put like this `HAVING [value1]=1`

Comment: select t.count as No_of_task from 
(SELECT COUNT(activity_task_id) count from activity_task_details where status !=4 and task_end_date < curdate())